# How to install Scid 4.6.2 in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: software-installation, chess

I've already downloaded the Scid-4.2.6.exe but I don't know how to get it running.

Comment: An .exe is a Windows executable that you won't be able to run natively in Ubuntu. What you need to do is find the software in either the software centre or as a liunx package online. Take a read of the following: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu, `.exe` files are not executable. These are Windows executables.

To install this, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to go to a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install scid
```

for further information, look [here](http://scid.sourceforge.net/download.html)

[image: Imgur]

Comment: Do i need to install the tcl-tk thing before I proceed with the scid installation?

Comment: yes @T.Yambao ....firt install scid,nearly 109MB

Comment: @Ravan: Could you please review my [edits](http://askubuntu.com/posts/664171/revisions) and also review the [editing help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of your answers in the future... **;-)**

Comment: Ok @Fabby,your advice always welcome :-)

Comment: Invalid operation scid

Comment: what it mean @T.Yambao ??

Comment: I don't know, but I have already installed  Scid vs Pc, following an instruction I've watched in Youtube.

Comment: This installs 4.5.1 I believe and not 4.6.x as asked for in the question.