# How to install latest Scid version?

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install [Scid](http://scid.sourceforge.net/) for chess analysis on Ubuntu but even though I am trying to follow instructions in the README and online, I cant seem to compile it properly to get an install to work.

It seems that people have been installing Scid using apt-get shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/664168/how-to-install-scid-4-6-2-in-ubuntu-14-04), but this version is somewhere around 4 years old, so I would like to get a more up to date version.

I am using 15.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compile and use the latest `scid` version (as of today 4.6) yourself :

1. Download :

   ```
   wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/scid/Scid/Scid%204.6/scid-4.6.2.zip
   unzip scid-4.6.2.zip
   ```
2. Compile :

   ```
   sudo apt-get install tk8.6 tcl8.6-dev
   cd scid-src 
   ./configure
   make
   ```
3. Launch :

   ```
   ./scid
   ```

Alternatively you can install it using `checkinstall`:

```
    sudo apt-get install checkinstall
    sudo checkinstall
```

Why `checkinstall` ?

> CheckInstall keeps track of all files installed by "make install" or
>   equivalent.   It creates a .deb package and adds it to the installed
>   packages database.   This allows easy package removal later. —  [Ubuntu Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall)

---

<sup>Successfully tested on my Ubuntu 15.04.</sup>

Comment: Use `checkinstall` instead of `make install` =)

Comment: @A.B. Great point =) done.

Comment: Worked beautifully, thanks for the help. And never knew about checkinstall this seems really useful.

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/scid/wiki/CompileScid/

Comment: checkinstall didn't work with the lated scid 4.6.4